# Whose body is in the rain puddle in The Matrix Revolutions?

Tags: the-matrix-revolutions

At the conclusion of the final battle between Neo and Mr. Smith in ***The Matrix Revolutions***, there is a body laying in a large puddle created by the rain.

Whose body is it?

Comment: Not an answer because I do not have the time to check the movie now, but from memory it was the body of the Oracle, as it was the last incarnation of the Duplicating Agent Smith, when he gained the Oracle's knowledge.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It's [the Oracle's (source: Matrix Wiki)](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Showdown_in_Mega_City):

> After Smith and all of his clones were destroyed, the Oracle's body
>   returned to the Matrix and reloaded into the puddle on the bottom of
>   the crater where Neo and Smith confronted during their duel and all
>   those who were assimilated by Smith returned back to their normal
>   selves in the Matrix.